# Homology Group of $S^2 \times S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to compute the homology groups $H_k(S^2\times S^2)$ , preferably without using the Maier Vietoris sequence or the Künneth formula.
I already computed $H_k(S^2\vee S^2)$, so I would like to use the following exact sequence of homology groups to solve this problem if it is even possible to solve it this way:
$$H_k(S^2\vee S^2)\rightarrow H_k(S^2\times S^2)\rightarrow H_k(S^2\times S^2,S^2\vee S^2)$$
However I am not able to compute $H_k(S^2\times S^2,S^2\vee S^2)$ using any of the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms.
Any help to compute this group or ideas for other approaches would be extremly helpful.
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You could try identifying the quotient space $(S^2\times S^2)/(S^2\vee S^2)$; looking up "smash product" may help.

Comment: Another approach is to use cellular homology; $S^2 \times S^2$ has a very easy-to-describe cell structure and for dimension reasons the cellular chain complex's boundary maps are very easy to compute.

Comment: Also posted today: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845416/42781