# Compute homology of $S^2 \times S^2$ with Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to compute the singular homology groups of $S^2 \times S^2$ by applying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, but I'm stuck in the process.

If it helps, in the same exercise I already calculated the homology groups of $S^2 \vee S^2$ and $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4$, so maybe I can derive the solution from these results somehow?

Comment: Also posted today: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845301/42781

Comment: Hint: $S^n\wedge S^m\simeq S^{n+m}$ and $S^n\wedge S^m=(S^n\times S^m)/(S^n\vee S^m)$.